# how to make vim indentation file type specific?

Tags: tab-characters

I usually work on js files and php files. My js files require 2 spaces tab, whereas my php requires 4. How can I make vim dynamically change that depending on the file type I'm working on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting these in your `.vimrc` should do the trick:

```
augroup FileTypeSpecificAutocommands
    autocmd FileType javascript setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
    autocmd FileType php setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
augroup END
```

You should also use expandtab to convert tabs into spaces, I think. Also, you might wanna check out [this blogpost](http://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html).

Also, if you don't mind splitting up your vimrc in modular files, you can put the following commands in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` and `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`

```
setlocal tabstop = softtabstop = shiftwidth = 2
```

Comment: ideology is kind of a big word to be put in a vim forum don't you think? 

Comment: what should I use then?

Comment: 'Ideology' sounds fine to me. It's a war after all...us against them! ;)

Comment: This kind of settings should be in a ftplugin rather than in autocommands because with autocommands the `filetype` is tested for each autocommand which is not efficient and this is also replicating something vim already does automatically. Also, if you stick with using autocommands it is usually a good idea to put them in an `augroup`.

Comment: @statox, fixed it. Sorry, it took so long. I was visiting through all my answers to check if I could add something new.